# how to read pdf file through C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

i have pdf file and i need to read the text and to insert to any val.

how do to it with C# (winform) ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Also need more detail. Do you want to populate the values of form fields, or do you want to insert read-only text in specific places?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) there's some sample code here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need a PDF library of some sort. [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) can reportedly do this - create and edit pdf files.

Comment: thank's for the help,

but in those sample i can only make new pdf file.

and i need only to read the text from pdf file to any val in my C# program

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the contents of a pdf file, you will need a 3rd party dll file like the above mentioned ITextSharp or PDFSharp. But if you only want to display the pdf file to the user of the application, then you can use web browser control. provided that you have adobe acrobat installed.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous User said, try it with iTextSharp.
For this, I read out the whole PDF and post the whole PDF and return it, for example to put it into a textbox:

```
public string ReadPdfFile(object Filename)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)Filename);
            string strText = string.Empty;

            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)Filename);
                String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                strText = strText + s;
                reader.Close();
            }
            return strText;
        }
```